# A way to remove click events for element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onclick, event-bubbling

I have an element `#foo` and it has click event on it. Element `#foo` is in element `#bar` which also has click event on it.

```
<div id="bar">
  <div id="foo" />
</div>
```

When `#foo` is clicked, `#bar` event gets called and `#foo` event gets ignored. That's now what I want.

I'm looking for a way to remove all click events from `#foo` element except my just set event **and** all events that are on parents for `#foo`.

**Edit:** Here is [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9WAUC/8/). I want 2nd event to get called before 1st event.

**Edit #2:** Here is [my code with your suggestions](http://jsfiddle.net/9WAUC/4/). Doesn't work.

Comment: The topmost onclick event will be processed first according to event delegation model.

Comment: Ok, have you tried anything?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, but I suppose I need to recursivly go up DOM tree and remove events.

Comment: *When `#foo` is clicked, `#bar` event gets called and `#foo` event gets ignored.* That's only true, if it has been especially taken care of. Otherwise, both events would be called. First `#foo` then `#bar`.

Comment: Your `#foo` element has no content, are you sure you're actually clicking on it?

Comment: That's just an example. It actually has content.

Comment: @daGrevis The following would help: The jQuery code you're using to bind the event handlers, and a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) (or equivalent) example that demonstrates the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a click event on foo and you dont want it to bubble you could do the following:

```
$("#foo").on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation(); //this line will stop the click bubbling up the tree.
});
```

Comment: Hmm, in my example this doesn't work. Actual situation is that there's an `$("body").on("click", "#foo", ...` and then like 5 nodes to the up there is `$("#baz .select").click( ...`. I added those lines to first event, but it doesn't get event called!

Comment: Updated question with code that shows: your suggestion doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#foo').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation(); 
     $('#bar').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Calling `e.preventDefault()` won't prevent the event from bubbling to `#bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Use stopPropagation function, see an example:

```
$("#foo").click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
})
```